# Check if object is null without using ==

Tags: c#, object, null, overloading, operation

In my program, I have objects derived from Dictionary. I need to check if 2 objects are equal, so I made an overload operator ==.

But at a later point, I need to check if a object is null.

```
If (object == null)  
{...}
```

So at this point, the program goes into the overload operation I have defined, but will throw a NullReferenceException, since one of the objects to compare is null.

So within the overload operation, I need to check if one object is null, but without using ==, since that would give me a StackOverflowException.

How can I check this?

Comment: Why not in your overloaded '==' do a try-catch to handle the null objects?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> In my program, I have objects derived from Dictionary.

I would strongly reconsider deriving from `Dictionary` in the first place. That's very rarely a good idea. Favour composition over inheritance in general, and think *very* carefully about how you want equality (and hash codes) to behave in the face of mutable data. It's usually a bad sign if two objects are equal at one point and then not equal later.

> So at this point, the program goes into the overload operation I have defined, but will throw a NullReferenceException, since one of the objects to compare is null.

*That's* the problem. Your overloaded `==` operator should *not* throw an exception - it should compare the value with `null`.

Typically an overload of `==` looks something like this:

```
public static bool ==(Foo left, Foo right)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(left, null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Equals should be overridden, and should be handling the case where
    // right is null (by checking with ReferenceEquals too). Also consider
    // implementing IEquatable<Foo>
    return left.Equals(right);
}
```

Here [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals) is used to perform the reference identity comparison. You *could* use this outside (in the code that you're currently considering changing) but it would be cleaner just to make `==` behave correctly.

Comment: Thank you. Using ReferenceEquals(left, null) worked.

Answer (score 5):

You either need to cast to object,

```
(object)obj == null
```

or use `object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null);`
(object is not a nice name for an object)

Comment: actually yea you were first +1:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for null in your implementation of overriden ==, following these guidelines for example : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

You could also use

```
object.ReferenceEquals(myInstance, null);
```

Please note that overriding base operators such as == and/or directly overriding .Net base types such as Dictionary are both not very good practices.

Answer (score 0):

overriding the == operator, as you have discovered, has non-obvious side effects and generally should be avoided.

You might consider having your object implement IComparable instead, and then calling CompareTo instead of ==.

Answer (score 0):

use the is null operator from c# 7

`if(object is null)...`